# How to get the current taxonomy term ID (not the slug) in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress, taxonomy

I've created a taxonomy.php page in my WordPress theme folder. I would like to get the current term id for a function. 
How can I get this?

`get_query_var('taxonomy')` only returns the term slug, I want the ID

Answer (score 352, accepted):

Nevermind! I found it :)

```
get_queried_object()->term_id;
```

Comment: You could also just use `get_queried_object_id()` to retrieve just the ID. Whole snippet would be `$term_id = get_queried_object_id();`

Comment: Good answer . Recently i see an question in WordPress stack exchange . Could you please check . http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/214453/taxonomy-subtaxonomy-child-taxonomy-of-a-product-woocommerce

Comment: Bear in mind this will work only in taxonomy page. But if you in taxonomy child page you won't get the taxonomy id.

Answer (score 76):

Simple and easy!

```
get_queried_object_id()
```

Comment: [get_queried_object_id()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_queried_object_id/) was introduced in 3.1.0 (February 23, 2011) and should be the correct answer for the question asked.


> `taxonomy.php` page in my wordpress template folder, I would like to get the current `term id` for a function.

Answer (score 45):

Here's the whole code snippet needed:

```
$queried_object = get_queried_object();
$term_id = $queried_object->term_id;
```

Answer (score 24):

**Use following code**

This will print your current taxonomy name and description(optional)

```
<?php 
   $tax = $wp_query->get_queried_object();
   echo ''. $tax->name . '';
   echo "<br>";
   echo ''. $tax->description .''; 
?>
```

Answer (score 15):

If you are in taxonomy page.

That's how you get all details about the taxonomy.

```
get_term_by( 'slug', get_query_var( 'term' ), get_query_var( 'taxonomy' ) );
```

This is how you get the taxonomy id

```
$termId = get_term_by( 'slug', get_query_var( 'term' ), get_query_var( 'taxonomy' ) )->term_id;
```

---

But if you are in post page (taxomony -> child)

```
$terms = wp_get_object_terms( get_queried_object_id(), 'taxonomy-name');
$term_id = $terms[0]->term_id;
```

Answer (score 10):

```
<?php 
$terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'taxonomy');
foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
    $termID[] = $term->term_id;
}
echo $termID[0]; 
?>
```

Answer (score 4):

See [**wp_get_post_terms()**](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_post_terms), you'd do something like so:

```
global $post;
$terms = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, 'YOUR_TAXONOMY_NAME',array('fields' => 'ids') );

print_r($terms);
```

Answer (score 2):

It's the term slug you want.Looks like you can get the id like this if that's what you need:

```
function get_term_link( $term, $taxonomy = '' ) {
    global $wp_rewrite;

    if ( !is_object($term) ) {
        if ( is_int( $term ) ) {
            $term = get_term( $term, $taxonomy );
        } else {
            $term = get_term_by( 'slug', $term, $taxonomy );
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This works on all page types not just taxonomy term archives

```
$category_id = get_the_category( get_the_ID());
$id          = get_category($category_id[0]->term_id);
```