# Get the term_taxonomy_id for the current template in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have managed to pull out all taxonomy terms stored on my WP site like this:

```
$terms = get_terms( 
             array (
                'taxonomy' => 'portfolio-category',
                'hide_empty' => false,
             ));   

print "<pre>";
print_r($terms);
print "</pre>";
```

This would give me something like this back:

```
[4] => WP_Term Object
    (
        [term_id] => 74
        [name] => Homepage Thumbnail
        [slug] => homepage-thumbnail
        [term_group] => 0
        [term_taxonomy_id] => 74
        [taxonomy] => portfolio-category
        [description] => 
        [parent] => 0
        [count] => 11
        [filter] => raw
        [term_order] => 0
    )
```

But what if I have a page like `www.mysite.com/portfolio-category/homepage-thumbnail` where `portfolio-category` is the taxonomy and `homepage-thumbnail` is the slug, as they are both in the URL is there a way I can grab the `term_taxonomy_id` for the current page?

Comment: All is explained on this reply: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12289169/how-do-i-get-current-taxonomy-term-id-on-wordpress

Comment: That gets the queried object, which is not what I want, I want to get the term_taxonomy_id based on the current page as the taxonomy slug is in the URL, at that point there is no queried object.